# What is best way to get CSV file data into database? Python (Falcon), Angular, MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, angular, csv, falconframework

Currently I am working in a project where user will be able to upload a CSV file and the data in CSV file will be stored into database. This project is developing on Falcon Framework as back-end where API requests are sending from client side Angular 4.

From Angular side, I can parse CSV file data into JSON data. There are some packages available as example ngx-papaparse. Is there other way around like getting CSV file in python and process CSV file data to be stored into database. Then what is the best way to do.

Comment: It's not clear what is your problem. But you can alsways send the file from the application's client side (in Angular, usually using HttpClientModule) to the server side and "do the magic" there.

Comment: Thank you.I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

`Python` is quite flexible for processing data, you may also convert your `csv` data to `json` using `Pandas` in python

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df.to_json('jsonfilename.json')
```

You can also store `csv` files in `mysql` by exporting them using python , please read http://www.vallinme.com/v1/?p=95

[Petl](http://petl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) is another library for such purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Will check the resources.